# RevTEX 4-2 citation for consecutive paper won't compress

Tags: bibliographies, revtex, multiple-citations

I am currently working on paper with a template from AIP. They uses Revtex4-2 as document class with extra (something on the square bracket, I don't know the term). There are several consecutive papers that I need to cite. The [guide](https://ctan.math.illinois.edu/macros/latex/contrib/revtex/auguide/auguide4-2.pdf) claims that the `\cite` command will automatically collapse the citation number, e.g. `[1,2,3,5] -> [1-3,5]` but that does not work for me. Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[%
 aip,
% jmp,
% bmf,
% sd,
% rsi,
cp,  % Conference Proceedings
 amsmath,amssymb,%nobibnotes,
% preprint,%
 reprint,%
%author-year,%
%author-numerical,%
]{revtex4-2}

\usepackage{graphicx}% Include figure files
\usepackage{dcolumn}% Align table columns on decimal point
\usepackage{bm}% bold math
%\usepackage[mathlines]{lineno}% Enable numbering of text and display math
%\linenumbers\relax % Commence numbering lines

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%% Loads a Times-like font. You can also load
%% {newtxtext,newtxtmath}, but not {times}, 
%% {txfonts} nor {mathtpm} as these packages
%% are obsolete and have been known to cause problems.
\usepackage{mathptmx} 

\begin{document}

\title{Title}% Force line breaks with \\

\author{Author's Name} % Write as First name Surname
 \email[Corresponding author: ]{first.author@insitution.edu}
\affiliation{
  Replace this text with an author's affiliation
  (use complete addresses, including country name or code).% Force line breaks with \\ if necessary
}


\begin{abstract}
This is abstract
\end{abstract}

\maketitle

\section{INTRODUCTION}

In the last couple of decades, the dynamics of magnetic \cite{zhu2012study, handoko2015scanning, zhang2017spin, szambolics2009domain, metaxas2007creep}.
\\
In the last couple of decades, the dynamics of magnetic \cite{zhu2012study, handoko2015scanning, zhang2017spin, metaxas2007creep}.

\section{Conclusion}

In this section we welcome you to include a summary of the end results of your research.

\begin{acknowledgments}
This is something to acknowledge.
\end{acknowledgments}

\nocite{*}
\bibliography{aipsamp}% Produces the bibliography via BibTeX.

\end{document}
%
% ****** End of file aipsamp.tex ******
```

And this is my aipsamp.bib

```
@article{zhu2012study,
  title={The study of perpendicular magnetic anisotropy in CoFeB sandwiched by MgO and tantalum layers using polarized neutron reflectometry},
  author={Zhu, T and Yang, Y and Yu, RC and Ambaye, H and Lauter, V and Xiao, JQ},
  journal={Applied Physics Letters},
  volume={100},
  number={20},
  pages={202406},
  year={2012},
  publisher={American Institute of Physics}
}

@article{handoko2015scanning,
  title={Scanning transmission X-ray microscopy study of the stretched magnetic-domain structure of Co/Pt multilayers under an in-plane field},
  author={Handoko, Djati and Quach, Duy-Truong and Lee, Sang-Hyuk and Shim, Je-Ho and Kim, Dong-Hyun and Lee, Kyung-Min and Jeong, Jong-Ryul and Kim, Namdong and Shin, Hyun-Joon},
  journal={Journal of the Korean Physical Society},
  volume={66},
  pages={1732--1735},
  year={2015},
  publisher={Springer}
}

@article{zhang2017spin,
  title={Spin-orbit-torque-induced magnetic domain wall motion in Ta/CoFe nanowires with sloped perpendicular magnetic anisotropy},
  author={Zhang, Yue and Luo, Shijiang and Yang, Xiaofei and Yang, Chang},
  journal={Scientific reports},
  volume={7},
  number={1},
  pages={2047},
  year={2017},
  publisher={Nature Publishing Group UK London}
}


@article{szambolics2009domain,
  title={Domain wall motion in ferromagnetic systems with perpendicular magnetization},
  author={Szambolics, Helga and Toussaint, J-Ch and Marty, Alain and Miron, Ioan Mihai and Buda-Prejbeanu, LD},
  journal={Journal of magnetism and magnetic materials},
  volume={321},
  number={13},
  pages={1912--1918},
  year={2009},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}

@article{metaxas2007creep,
  title={Creep and flow regimes of magnetic domain-wall motion in ultrathin Pt/Co/Pt films with perpendicular anisotropy},
  author={Metaxas, PJ and Jamet, JP and Mougin, A and Cormier, M and Ferr{\'e}, J and Baltz, Vincent and Rodmacq, B and Dieny, B and Stamps, RL},
  journal={Physical review letters},
  volume={99},
  number={21},
  pages={217208},
  year={2007},
  publisher={APS}
}
```

I thought the references need to be cited first so it would work after the next citation. Hence the extra copy of the sentence below. But still, nothing happened. Can someone help me? Sorry if my english is messy.

Disclaimer: I am using Overleaf. Only two files exist in the project, the main `.tex` file and `aipsamp.bib` file.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compression of citations does generally work in REVTeX, and will for non-AIP styles, as well as the root `aip` substyle, but you are using the `cp` option with the AIP substyles which stops compression of citations from `[1,2,3,5]` to `[1-3,5]`.
As the [Author’s Guide to AIP Substyles for REVTeX 4.2](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/revtex/aip/aipguide4-2.pdf) indicates the correct class options for specifying an AIP journal style would indeed be `aip,cp`, the natural inference is that the use of uncompressed citations is the correct style for AIP Conference Proceedings.

It is somewhat unfortunate that no mention of this AIP Conference Proceedings-specific behaviour is made in the [Author’s Guide to AIP Substyles for REVTeX 4.2](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/revtex/aip/aipguide4-2.pdf) (indeed no mention of the AIP class option `cp` is made at all), and if you think this is a bug it should be flagged (as specific to the AIP substyles) to the AIP.

Omitting the `cp` class option will give compressed citations but this clearly changes the appearance of the document, similarly omitting the `aip` class option appears to cause the `cp` class option to be ignored and produce a standard `aps`-style document.

Multiple references in a single bibliography entry (Sec VIII.5. of the REVTeX 4.2 Author's Guide) does work under `aip,cp` and so you can instead use `\cite{zhu2012study,*handoko2015scanning,*zhang2017spin, szambolics2009domain, metaxas2007creep}` to generate `[1,2,3]` where `1` is a single bibliography entry containing the three references `zhu2012study`, `handoko2015scanning` and `zhang2017spin`, which will make the subsequent block `[1,3]`.

The settings of the `cp` class option can be overriden to force compression of citations with

```
\makeatletter
\def\NAT@cmprs{\@ne}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Unfortunately, it's been a common agreement for us editors to use compression for 3 or more citation. I actually wanted to try to do it manually for the "range-able" citation, but it will affect the occurence counting of the citation. I got a little hack to get what i want. I will write in for a new answer

Comment: @Realm143 see edit.  I don't know who you editors are, but as said, if you think it shouldn't be this way, then file a bug with the AIP. The functionality generally works in REVTeX so this is an active (if not necessarily deliberate) choice within the AIP Conference Proceedings substyle.

Comment: Thank you!! It works like a charm. Maybe someday i will file the bug. Btw, do you mind if i ask where to modify the bibliography? I have another problem with bibliography format like i asked in my next question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/684236/revtex-4-2-modify-enumeration-of-bibliography).

Answer (score 1):

I will write my hack here if someone need it. So i used `\vphantom`. I am sure you can find the detail about that command elsewhere and have a better explanation than i would. Basically, it will hide the text (including the text horizontal width), but the file still know its presence (Sorry for the lack of a better word).

I write

```
In the last couple of decades, the dynamics of magnetic. \vphantom{\cite{zhu2012study, handoko2015scanning, zhang2017spin, szambolics2009domain, metaxas2007creep}}
```

then i add `[1-5]` in the end of the sentence

```
In the last couple of decades, the dynamics of magnetic [1-5]. \vphantom{\cite{zhu2012study, handoko2015scanning, zhang2017spin, szambolics2009domain, metaxas2007creep}} Next sentence ...
```

Fortunately, the paper i am working on does not have so many compressable citation so i am fine doing this. If someone have a better hack, please let us know.