# RevTex 4-2: Modify enumeration of bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, revtex

This is another problem i have with AIP template using Revtex 4-2 as document class. The problem is still about bibliography like my [previous](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/684205/revtex-4-2-citation-for-consecutive-paper-wont-compress) question. I need to do three things:

1. Make the alignment of enumeration to the left
2. Give extra space between enumeration number and the bibitem
3. Change bibliography font size

Here is my MWE, which is not that different from my [previous](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/684205/revtex-4-2-citation-for-consecutive-paper-wont-compress) question

```
\documentclass[%
 aip,
% jmp,
% bmf,
% sd,
% rsi,
cp,  % Conference Proceedings
 amsmath,amssymb,%nobibnotes,
% preprint,%
 reprint,%
%author-year,%
%author-numerical,%
]{revtex4-2}

\usepackage{graphicx}% Include figure files
\usepackage{dcolumn}% Align table columns on decimal point
\usepackage{bm}% bold math
%\usepackage[mathlines]{lineno}% Enable numbering of text and display math
%\linenumbers\relax % Commence numbering lines

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%% Loads a Times-like font. You can also load
%% {newtxtext,newtxtmath}, but not {times}, 
%% {txfonts} nor {mathtpm} as these packages
%% are obsolete and have been known to cause problems.
\usepackage{mathptmx} 

\begin{document}

\title{Title}% Force line breaks with \\

\author{Author's Name} % Write as First name Surname
\email[Corresponding author: ]{first.author@insitution.edu}
\affiliation{
  Replace this text with an author's affiliation
  (use complete addresses, including country name or code).% Force line breaks with \\ if necessary
}


\begin{abstract}
This is abstract
\end{abstract}

\maketitle

\section{INTRODUCTION}

In the last couple of decades, the dynamics of magnetic [1-5]. \vphantom{\cite{zhu2012study, handoko2015scanning, zhang2017spin, szambolics2009domain, metaxas2007creep}} Next sentence ...

\section{Conclusion}

In this section we welcome you to include a summary of the end results of your research.

\begin{acknowledgments}
This is something to acknowledge.
\end{acknowledgments}

\nocite{*}
\bibliography{aipsamp}% Produces the bibliography via BibTeX.

\end{document}
%
% ****** End of file aipsamp.tex ******
```

and the aipsamp.bib

```
@article{zhu2012study,
  title={The study of perpendicular magnetic anisotropy in CoFeB sandwiched by MgO and tantalum layers using polarized neutron reflectometry},
  author={Zhu et al., T},
  journal={Appl. Phys. Lett.},
  volume={100},
  number={20},
  pages={202406},
  year={2012},
  publisher={American Institute of Physics}
} %Applied Physics Letters

@article{handoko2015scanning,
  title={Scanning transmission X-ray microscopy study of the stretched magnetic-domain structure of Co/Pt multilayers under an in-plane field},
  author={Handoko et al., Djati},
  journal={J. Korean. Phys. Soc.},
  volume={66},
  pages={1732–1735},
  year={2015},
  publisher={Springer}
} %Journal of the Korean Physical Society 

@article{zhang2017spin,
  title={Spin-orbit-torque-induced magnetic domain wall motion in Ta/CoFe nanowires with sloped perpendicular magnetic anisotropy},
  author={Zhang\text{,} S. Luo\text{,} X. Yang \text{and} C. Yang, Yue},
  journal={Sci. Rep.},
  volume={7},
  number={1},
  pages={2047},
  year={2017},
  publisher={Nature Publishing Group UK London}
} %Scientific Reports

@article{fukami2008micromagnetic,
  title={Micromagnetic analysis of current driven domain wall motion in nanostrips with perpendicular magnetic anisotropy},
  author={Fukami\text{,} T. Suzuki\text{,} N. Ohshima\text{,} K. Nagahara \text{and} N. Ishiwata, S},
  journal={J. Appl. Phys.},
  volume={103},
  number={7},
  pages={07E718},
  year={2008},
  publisher={American Institute of Physics}
} %Journal of Applied Physics

@article{szambolics2009domain,
  title={Domain wall motion in ferromagnetic systems with perpendicular magnetization},
  author={Szambolics\text{,} J. C. Toussaint\text{,} A. Marty\text{,} I. M. Miron \text{and} L. D. Buda-Prejbeanu, Helga},
  journal={J. Magn. Magn. Mater.},
  volume={321},
  number={13},
  pages={1912–1918},
  year={2009},
  publisher={Elsevier}
} %Journal of magnetism and magnetic materials 

@article{metaxas2007creep,
  title={Creep and flow regimes of magnetic domain-wall motion in ultrathin Pt/Co/Pt films with perpendicular anisotropy},
  author={Metaxas et al., P J},
  journal={Phys. Rev. Lett.},
  volume={99},
  number={21},
  pages={217208},
  year={2007},
  publisher={APS}
} %Physical review letters

@article{burrowes2013low,
  title={Low depinning fields in Ta-CoFeB-MgO ultrathin films with perpendicular magnetic anisotropy},
  author={Burrowes et al., C},
  journal={Appl. Phys. Lett.},
  volume={103},
  number={18},
  pages={182401},
  year={2013},
  publisher={American Institute of Physics}
} %Applied Physics Letters

@article{hartmann2019creep,
  title={Creep of chiral domain walls},
  author={Hartmann\text{,} R. A. Duine\text{,} M. J. Meijer\text{,} H. J. Swagten \text{and} R. Lavrijsen, D M},
  journal={Phys. Rev. B},
  volume={100},
  number={9},
  pages={094417},
  year={2019},
  publisher={APS}
} %Physical Review B

@article{wang2014role,
  title={The role of inhomogeneity of perpendicular anisotropy in magnetic properties of ultra thin CoFeB film},
  author={Wang\text{,} D. Wei\text{,} K. Z. Gao\text{,} J. Cao \text{and} F. Wei, Y},
  journal={J. Appl. Phys.},
  volume={115},
  number={5},
  pages={053901},
  year={2014},
  publisher={American Institute of Physics}
} %Journal of Applied Physics

@misc{donahue1999oommf,
  title={OOMMF User's Guide, Version 1.0},
  author={Donahue, Michael and Porter, Donald},
  year={1999},
  publisher={National Institute of Standards and Technology Gaithersburg, MD}
}

@article{gilbert2004phenomenological,
  title={A phenomenological theory of damping in ferromagnetic materials},
  author={Gilbert, Thomas L},
  journal={IEEE Trans. Magn.},
  volume={40},
  number={6},
  pages={3443–3449},
  year={2004},
  publisher={IEEE}
} %IEEE Transactions on Magnetics
```

So from this,

[image: no left, no extra space]

i need to make the alignment of the enumeration to the left like this,

[image: left, no extra space]

and add space between enumeration and the bibitem like this.

[image: left, extra space]

To be precise, i need the length of blue segment to be 0.75 cm. I also want the font size to be 10, but apparently the default is 8. I have tried `\fontsize{*the fontsize*}{12}\selectfont` but the font size didn't change.

I know how to do this if this is a normal enumerate environment or such. But it seems Revtex4-2 complicates things so much. I have tried to modify the syntax of \bibliography from biblatex.sty such as labelwidth, biblabel, etc but it is still not working. Can someone help me?

Disclaimer: I am using Overleaf. Only two files exist in the project, the main `.tex` file and `aipsamp.bib` file.

Edit: I used aipnum4-2 as bibliography style. You can download it [here](https://www.aq-test.com/latex/texmf-dist/bibtex/bst/revtex/).

Comment: Off-topic: Many `author` fields appear to be styled in a rather unusual fashion, to put it mildly. E.g., `author={Zhang\text{,} S. Luo\text{,} X. Yang \text{and} C. Yang, Yue},` should be `author={Zhang, S. and Luo, X. and Yang, C. and Yang, Yue},`. In other entries, the "et al" particle seems placed rather oddly. E.g., the fields `author={Zhu et al., T},` and `author={Handoko et al., Djati},` should be `author={Zhu, T. and others},` and `author={Handoko, Djati and others},`, respectively. Observe that one should write "and others" rather than "et al.". Do fix these issues ASAP, please.

Comment: @Mico For the first comment, the author field is intentionally written like that to format agreement purposes. I suggest you just ignore that. For the second comment, the template actually provide aipnum4-2.bst, but once you compile, you can't make changes to the bibliography unless you deactivate it with %, compile, then activate it again ( i don't know why it works like that). If you want the .bst file, i will give you the link to download it.

Comment: I don't think `natbib`/`revtex` style the bibliography in any particularly abnormal way, so a good approach might be to first see if you can set up `article` with `\bibliographystyle{unsrt}` in the way you want, then try getting that to work with `natbib` and `\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}`, then try getting that to work with `revtex4-2`. This may also help to give a more focused question. The bst isn't particularly relevant it's mainly the `thebibliography` environment (and related macros) which `revtex` adapts from `natbib` which adapts from the standard classes.